# python : windows : Subporcess open a .bat file in a new command window and run

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I have a bat file in which it runs a python file

`test.bat`

```
python test.py
pause
```

the python code file is

`test.py`

```
print("Hello World")
```

Now i want to use suprocess and open a windows command prompt and run the .bat file

i tried creating a python script with subprocess

`test2.py`

```
import subprocess
filepath=r"D:\test.bat"
subprocess.Popen([filepath], shell=True)
```

Now I try to run this python file in command Promp and expecting another windows command prompt to open and run the test.py and pause, what i get is it does not open, but runs the bat file there itself

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1198]                                                                                                                     
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                
D:>python test2.py

D:>                                                                                                                                     
D:>python test.py                                                                                                                       
Hello World                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                
D:>pause                                                                                                                                
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of Windows's [start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) command, which starts a separate Command Prompt window to run a specified program or command:

```
import subprocess
filepath=r"D:\test.bat"
subprocess.Popen("start {}".format(filepath), shell=True)
```

Comment: Here i used pause. so it stops after completing the `python test.py` but then if i hit enter the window is closed. How to keep the window open with command prompt back

Comment: @Santhosh Yedidi: Use `subprocess.Popen("start cmd.exe @cmd /k {}".format(filepath), shell=True)`

Comment: can you explain what does @cmd \k does here

Answer (score 0):

Try to launch a command in a new command interpreter:

```
filepath=r"cmd /K D:\test.bat"
```